# Django WizardView with both ModelForm and ModelFormSet (this one not rendering)

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, django-formwizard

I am trying to create a FormWizard, so that a user enters a 'date' only once (on step 1) and then (on step 2), enters some names with associated amounts.
For each 'name' and associated 'amount', I want to save an instance of a Model (fields: date, name, amount).

For step 2, I tried using a FormSet, but the Wizard view is simply not rendering any fields. It shows only "step 2 of 2" and a Submit button.

```
# In forms.py

class FormForDate(forms.Form):
'''Only for date'''

    date = forms.DateField(initial = datetime.date.today()) 

class AccountaModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Account #model has 3 field: name, date, amount
        exclude = ['date']

class AccountsFormSet(forms.Form):

    amount_formset = modelformset_factory(Account, form=AccountaModelForm, extra=10, exclude=('date'))
    amount_s_formset = amount_formset(queryset=Account.objects.none(),)
```

In urls.py (among others):

```
url(r'^form/$', AccountMultiple.as_view([FormForDate, AccountsFormSet]))
```

And in views.py

```
class AccountMultiple(SessionWizardView):

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        for form in form_list:
            print form #I am just doing something

        return render_to_response('app/formset.html', {
            'form': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

Am I doing something wrong in this code? 
Or is it a problem with the template (I used the one from Django docs: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#creating-templates-for-the-forms))
Or is there a third possibility I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

- Your `AccountsFormSet` does not seem to be modelformset  as its derived from `Form`.
- `WizardView.done()` method is called when last step is submitted and form is valid. So rendering formset there may not be what you want.
- You need to specify different template that renders the formset properly for Step 2.